# How do I Deserialize this XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fruit>
  <Fruit_group name='Tropical'>
    <fruit_types name ='Tropical Used'>
        <fruit>bananas</fruit>
        <fruit>mangoes</fruit>
    </fruit_types>
  </Fruit_group>
  <Fruit_group name='Citrus'>
    <fruit_types name ='Citruses Used'>
      <fruit>orange</fruit>
      <fruit>lime</fruit>
      <fruit>grapefruit</fruit>
      <excluded_fruits>
         <fruit>mandarin</fruit>
      </excluded_fruits>
    </fruit_types>
  </Fruit_group>
</Fruit>
```

And this is a sample of my XML text..
Is there a way to deserialize it and keep the name of the elements too.. 
    I mean I would like to have like:

```
Tropical -> Tropical Used -> fruit -> bananas, mangoes

Citrus->Citruses Used -> 
fruit = orange, lime, grapefruit
excluded = mandarin....
Something like this...
```

Could someone help me to understand how does this work?

Comment: Have you looked up deserialisation with c# (c# deserialise XML to model)? Create a model for your XML structure and then you cna use/print it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML to c#](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net) website to create a class according to XML.

In this case, I've got this example

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
[XmlRoot(ElementName="fruit_types")]
public class Fruit_types {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="fruit")]
    public List<string> Fruit { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="excluded_fruits")]
    public Excluded_fruits Excluded_fruits { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Fruit_group")]
public class Fruit_group {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="fruit_types")]
    public Fruit_types Fruit_types { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="excluded_fruits")]
public class Excluded_fruits {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="fruit")]
    public string Fruit { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Fruit")]
public class Fruit {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Fruit_group")]
    public List<Fruit_group> Fruit_group { get; set; }
}

}
```

Also, You could read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-1) about XML deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to convert the `XML` to `Model` and do required alterations. For example change the `string` to `List<string>` under `Excluded_fruits`

```
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "fruit_types")]
public class Fruit_types
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fruit")]
    public List<string> Fruit { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "excluded_fruits")]
    public Excluded_fruits Excluded_fruits { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fruit_group")]
public class Fruit_group
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fruit_types")]
    public Fruit_types Fruit_types { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "excluded_fruits")]
public class Excluded_fruits
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fruit")]
    public List<string> Fruit { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fruit")]
public class Fruit
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fruit_group")]
    public List<Fruit_group> Fruit_group { get; set; }
}
```

Once the model is ready, you can use `XmlSerializer` to `Deserialize` the xml file

```
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(xmlfilepath))
        {
            string xmlString = r.ReadToEnd();

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruit));

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                var fruits = (Fruit)ser.Deserialize(reader);

                foreach(var fruitgroup in fruits.Fruit_group)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{fruitgroup.Name} -> ");
                    Console.Write($"{fruitgroup.Fruit_types.Name} -> ");
                    Console.Write($"fruit = {string.Join(",", fruitgroup.Fruit_types.Fruit.ToArray())}; ");
                    if (fruitgroup.Fruit_types.Excluded_fruits?.Fruit?.Count() > 0)
                        Console.Write($"excluded = {string.Join(",", fruitgroup.Fruit_types.Excluded_fruits.Fruit.ToArray())}{Environment.NewLine}");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like getting flatter results doing a custom parsing using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Fruit_Group> groups = doc.Descendants("Fruit_group").Select(x => new Fruit_Group()
            {
                groupName = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                typeName = (string)x.Element("fruit_types").Attribute("name"),
                fruits = x.Elements("fruit_types").Elements("fruit").Select(y => (string)y).ToArray(),
                excluded = x.Descendants("excluded_fruits").Elements("fruit").Select(y => (string)y).ToArray()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Fruit_Group
    {
        public string groupName { get; set;}
        public string typeName { get; set; }
        public string[] fruits { get; set; }
        public string[] excluded { get; set; }
    }
}
```